# Parsing Print output from 4 data source

Tags: python, snmp

EDIT:
Sorry for the delay....  This is still giving me issues -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmp1.py", line 18, in <module>
    print_snmp_event(varBindTableRow)
  File "snmp1.py", line 7, in print_snmp_event
    print '{1} = {3}'.format(*data)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

That is the output I get when I try and run your latest suggestion.

---

I am having issues printing this correctly  I am running SNMP on a router and I am getting the following as an output on print.  I am using pysnmp to send this data to the router.

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
        cmdgen.CommunityData('STRING'),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('router', 161)),
        '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2','1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14'
)


for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
    print varBindTableRow
```

My output is

```
[(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.222), OctetString('Gi4/2')), (ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.215), Counter32(0))]
```

What I want to get is

```
Gi4/2 = 0
```

I would think i could printout 1,3 but its not working.  Anyone have any tips?

Sorry here is the output:

```
print type(varBindTableRow[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
print type(varBindTableRow[0][0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
print repr(varBindTableRow)
[[(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1), OctetString('FastEthernet0/0')), (ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14.1), Counter32(0))],
print repr(varBindTableRow[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
print repr(varBindTableRow[0][0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

When I run the script you gave, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snmp_pull.py", line 18, in <module>
    print_snmp_event(varBindTableRow)
  File "snmp_pull.py", line 7, in print_snmp_event
    print '{1} = {3}'.format(*data)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: So this is more of an SNMP question than an actual Python question?

Comment: Rather looks like the opposite to me. Maybe some more context could be provided by the asker?

Answer (score 0):

I'm *assuming* that the SNMP event stuff is a string that your program is trying to parse. If so, you can extract what you want use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) pattern, like this.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re

snmp_event = "[(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.222), OctetString('Gi4/2')), (ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.215), Counter32(0))]"

print snmp_event

pat = re.compile(r'\w+\((.*?)\)')
data = pat.findall(snmp_event)

print '{1} = {3}'.format(*data)
```

**Output:**

```
[(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.222), OctetString('Gi4/2')), (ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.15.215), Counter32(0))]
'Gi4/2' = 0
```

---

**Edit**

Aladine, I asked you to paste that info into your *original* question because it's **very** hard to read stuff like that in comments.

But I realise now that I made a bit of a mistake: I should've asked you to do this:

```
    print type(varBindTableRow[0])
    print type(varBindTableRow[0][0])
    print repr(varBindTableRow)
    print repr(varBindTableRow[0])
    print repr(varBindTableRow[0][0])
```

which would have to go inside your `for` loop .

Sorry about that. I *did* get a little bit of info from what you put into the comments. So try this. I can't guarantee that it'll work, and I can't test it because I don't have the SNMP stuff.

```
import re
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

def print_snmp_event(row):
    pat = re.compile(r'\w+\((.*?)\)')
    data = pat.findall(str(row))
    print '{1} = {3}'.format(*data)


cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
        cmdgen.CommunityData('STRING'),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('router', 161)),
        '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2','1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14'
)

for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
    print_snmp_event(varBindTableRow)
```

Please let me know if it works, and if it doesn't work ***please*** paste the results into your question (with indenting to preserve the lines, just like you paste code), **not** into a comment.

Comment: Still didnt work, I get the same output, I think the problem is when 

I do your code I get :
>>> type(snmp_event)
<type 'str'>

When I do mine:
>>> type(varBindTable)
<type 'tuple'>

Is there a way to do this to a tuple?

Comment: Ok. What do you get when you do `type(varBindTable[0])` and `type(varBindTable[0][0])` ? And what do you get when you do `print repr(varBindTable)`, `print repr(varBindTable[0])`, `print repr(varBindTable[0][0])` ? _Please_ paste these results into your original question.

Comment: >>> type(varBindTable[0])
**<type 'NoneType'>**
>>> type(varBindTable[0][0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable**
When I print repr(varBindTable) I get the entire Tuple
>>> print repr(varBindTable[0])
None
>>> print repr(varBindTable[0][0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable